# C Multiples different union in a struct

Tags: c

I have to access and write variable in different format, hex and float. To solve this problem I used unions allowing me to write the variable like a float or with Hex.

I used this in "big" struct because i had this problem multiples times.
Now running the program line by line i see it is writing in all unions at the same time. (on Eclipse C/C++ ) I definitely don't want that, is there a workaround to keep the unions but force them to be differents variables ?

I tried to invert the union name : stillingDia (before and after { uint32_t...})

```
// In Header file
typedef struct sensorParametersSensorSpecific{
    union {uint32_t i; float f;}stillingDia ;
    union {uint32_t i; float f;}stillingHei ;
}sensorParametersSensorSpecific_t;

//In another source file
void sensorSpecificInit(sensorParametersSensorSpecific_t* SS){
    SS->stillingDia.f   =100; // This write in the two union...
    SS->stillingHei.f   =0.5;
}

// in my main code
int main(){
    struct sensorParametersSensorSpecific SS;
    sensorSpecificInit(&SS);
    printf("Dia : %f\n",SS.stillingDia.f); // prints 100.000000
    printf("hei : %f\n",SS.stillingHei.f); // prints 0.5 (problem solved ?)
return 0;
}
```

I would like it to write in each union behaving like separate variables…
Maybe there is a smarter way, I'm open for every hint.

Comment: I would say "[mcve] or it didn't happen".

Comment: The elements in a union share space.  Writing to any one of them will, in general, overwrite all of the others.  The two unions are independent of each other and should not affect each other.  Storage is only shared *within* a union.

Comment: No I was expecting it to behave separately : an f for stillingDia and another f for stillinghei…

Comment: @TomKarzes, the OP has multiple unions in one struct and supposedly writing in one of the unions overwrites another.

Comment: *Within* a union, storage is shared.  Between *different* unions, it is not (unless they are contained in a parent union, which is not your case).  Assigning to dia does *not* affect hei, and vice versa.

Comment: Yes, @r3musn0x, that's what the OP *says*.  And I find that highly doubtful.  I'm with molbdnilo here: show me the MRE that proves it.

Comment: @r3musn0x If that's really what OP believes, then OP is jumping to an invalid conclusion.  But I don't see anything in the posted code that would distinguish the two cases, so I don't see how OP can make that claim.

Comment: @TomKarzes How should i do to make different union? Because i thought i was the way.

I made that claim from the debug perspective in eclipse showing me all my union in my struct changing at the same line.

Comment: @Arnaud The code you posted works.  You are mistaken in thinking that writing to dia affects hei and vice versa.  You are claiming to see a problem that your posted code doesn't demonstrate.

Comment: ... and if you maintain otherwise, then again, MRE.  You have updated the code to a complete program, but not one that demonstrates your claim in any observable way.

Comment: @TomKarzes Is it really ? I really sure all unions change value to 100 at the line SS->stillingDia.f (the code you see is only a part, there is more union in fact)

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes i understand that, but i can't take you a screenshot of my screen to upload it on stack am I wrong ?

Comment: Start with the code you posted.  Right before `main` returns, print `f` from both unions.  You will see `100.0` and `0.5`.  It works.  If there is a bug, it's in the code that you *didn't* post.

Comment: @TomKarzes Right before ? my variable aren't declared this soon no ?

I've tried _printf_ just after _sensorSpecificInit_, it prints 100.000 and 100.000

Comment: You have two different pieces of code:  (1) the code you didn't post, which you claim doesn't work, and (2) the code you posted, which does work.

Comment: After the call to `sensorSpecificInit` and before the `return`.  So yes, `SS` will be defined at that point.  `sensorSpecificInit` defines the `f` field of both unions.  And you should not see `100.0` twice, you should see `100.0` and `0.5`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195518/discussion-between-arnaud-and-tom-karzes).

Comment: @Arnaud, I took your code and modified it along the lines Tom describes.  I gave SS an initializer in `main()`, and printed out both `f` values before the call to `sensorSpecificInit()`, inside that function between the two assignments, and after the function returns.  The output showed exactly what I expected: writing to one union affected only that union.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I really don't know what to say, it just don't happen this way on my computer…

Comment: I don't know how to read I wrote to time the same variable in my main, now it works, but clearly there must be a bug in eclipse the variable show the same value….

Comment: I could believe that Eclipse misled you, but I think we've just established that indeed, your question is based on a faulty premise.  The program behavior you claimed does not, in fact, occur.

Comment: @Arnaud It is not a bug in Eclipse. You're printing out the same variable both times and calling it something else.

Comment: Look at this link, there is a picture oh what have been mistaken me : [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GDWjVYWexWMlj3A3XSnkdZWklLFpyAcY)
The double printf with the same value was a mistake but not the one i was looking for, what let me think all my values changes at the same time was the Eclipse debugging perspective (the right windows on my screen capture showing the variables)

Comment: @Arnaud That's a bug in Eclipse. Go email them or something, or ask a new question about Eclipse.

Comment: Okay, what should I open a ticket or just email ? (Don't really know what to do)

Answer (score 1):

You're printing the same variable for each call of `printf`.

This:

```
printf("hei : %f\n",SS.stillingDia.f); // prints 100.000000
```

should be this:

```
printf("hei : %f\n",SS.stillingHei.f); // doesn't print 100.000000
```

The fact that Eclipse says otherwise, well... what do you expect?